# Usort by specific string value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of products. Each product is associative array and has an id, language type and product type id.

```
[1] => ["1", "en", "1"],
[2] => ["3", "fr", "1"],
[3] => ["7", "es", "1"],
[4] => ["2", "en", "2"],
[5] => ["4", "fr", "2"],
[6] => ["6", "es", "2"],
[7] => ["8", "en", "3"],
[8] => ["5", "ru", "3"],
```

I already sorted the array with product ids with usort

```
usort($data, function ($a, b) {

    return ($a['product_type_id'] - $b['product_type_id']);
});
```

I want to sort everything by product type id and after that I also want all items with language id 'en' appear in the beginning.

```
[1] => ["1", "en", "1"],
[2] => ["2", "en", "2"],
[3] => ["8", "en", "3"],
[4] => ["3", "fr", "1"],
[5] => ["7", "es", "1"],
[6] => ["4", "fr", "2"],
[7] => ["6", "es", "2"],
[8] => ["5", "ru", "3"],
```

I played around with usort in many different ways to achieve these but was not able to. I even wrote a separate usort which takes the sorted array and only makes "en" to the top. After that sort "en" is on the top but order of product types are completely destroyed. This is my second usort

```
usort($dataSortedByProductTypeId, function ($a, $b) {
    if($a['language_id'] == 'en'){
        if($b['language_id'] == 'en'){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
$array = [
    ['id' => '1', 'lang' => 'en', 'pid' => '1'],
    ['id' => '3', 'lang' => 'fr', 'pid' => '1'],
    ['id' => '7', 'lang' => 'es', 'pid' => '1'],
    ['id' => '2', 'lang' => 'en', 'pid' => '2'],
    ['id' => '4', 'lang' => 'fr', 'pid' => '2'],
    ['id' => '6', 'lang' => 'es', 'pid' => '2'],
    ['id' => '8', 'lang' => 'en', 'pid' => '3'],
    ['id' => '6', 'lang' => 'ru', 'pid' => '3']
];

usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['lang'] == $b['lang']) {
        return ($a['pid'] - $b['pid']);
    }

    if ($a['lang'] == 'en') {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($b['lang'] == 'en') {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return ($a['pid'] - $b['pid']);
    }
});
```

Comment: This actually works but can you explain me a little how this works.

Comment: You're trying to sort by two different values, first by `lang` and then by `pid`, so all my ifs are basically saying `en` goes first, but if anything else happens, `return ($a['pid'] - $b['pid'])`.

Answer (score 0):

**array_multisort** will do this for you.

```
<?php
$ar = [
1 => ["1", "en", "1"],
2 => ["3", "fr", "1"],
3 => ["7", "es", "1"],
4 => ["2", "en", "2"],
5 => ["4", "fr", "2"],
6 => ["6", "es", "2"],
7 => ["8", "en", "3"],
8 => ["5", "ru", "3"]
];

define('ID',0);
define('LANGUAGE',1);
define('PRODUCT_ID',2);

foreach ($ar as $key => $row) {
        $language[$key] = $row[LANGUAGE];
        $productId[$key] = $row[PRODUCT_ID];
}
var_dump($ar);
array_multisort($productId, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC,$language, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $ar);
var_dump($ar);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: This does not do what was asked